# Unable to access path in phpGrid

Tags: php, gridview, datagrid, php-5.3

I'm  using http://phpgrid.com php datagrid.But it shows 2 errors and say unable to acccess path.Here is my path's and configurations,

phpgrid folder

> localhost:8090/MySite/admin/phpGrid

It Shows those 2 errors.

> Warning: require_once(/admin/phpGrid/conf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\mySite\admin\myGrid.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/admin/phpGrid/conf.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\mySite\admin\myGrid.php on line 2

Here is my php.conf file

```
 <?php
// mysql example

define('PHPGRID_DB_HOSTNAME','localhost'); // database host name
define('PHPGRID_DB_USERNAME', 'root');     // database user name
define('PHPGRID_DB_PASSWORD', ''); // database password
define('PHPGRID_DB_NAME', 'testdb'); // database name
define('PHPGRID_DB_TYPE', 'mysql');  // database type
define('PHPGRID_DB_CHARSET','utf8'); // ex: utf8(for mysql),AL32UTF8 (for oracle), leave blank to use the default charset

define('SERVER_ROOT', '/admin/phpGrid');

/******** DO NOT MODIFY ***********/
require_once('phpGrid.php');     
/**********************************/
?>
```

Here is myphp file(myGrid.php)

```
<?php
require_once("/admin/phpGrid/conf.php");

$dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM newtbl", "Id", "newtbl"); 

// change column titles
$dg->set_col_title("Id", "Number");
$dg->set_col_title("Name", "FirstName");


$dg -> display();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, i cannot add a command.

Where is the location of the myGrid.php related to the "/admin/phpGrid/conf.php" path?
The question is: is that the right path from your myGrid.php file to the conf.php file?